# LinkedIn OAuth 2.0 r_fullprofile

Tags: linkedin-api

Does anyone knows how I can request a r_fullprofile for my app? I currently have an app, but it only has a r_basicprofile.

Comment: I'm also trying to figure out this. I think you have to become LinkedIn Partner, but it's hard to find which kind of partnership you need to apply...

Comment: Just trying to find same info, no luck so far...

Answer (score 1):

I asked LinkedIn directly. They don't grant access to the full profile anymore. Sorry.

Comment: @JP.Aulet In what way doesn't this answer the question? Confirming that something is not possible is also an answer.

Comment: That's true, already deleted it and upvoted.